# Insertion into array in mongo not happening?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDb, and I have a question about the insertion of data. My mongoose schema for 'user' collection:

```
var user = new mongoose.Schema({

  username : {type: String},
  email    : {type: String,index: {unique: true}},
  password : {type: String},
  feed     : [{
                title       : {type: String},
                description : {type: String},
                latitude    : {type:Number},
                longitude   : {type:Number},
                feedImages  : [{
                                imageUrl: {type: String}
                              }]
             }]
});
```

I want to insert data to the feedimages and my service for that is:

```
app.post('/uploadFeedImage',function(req,res) {
    var _id         = req.body._id;
    var imageUrl    = req.body.imageUrl;
    db.user.update(
        {"feed._id":_id },
        {$push : {
            feedImages:{
                imageUrl:imageUrl
            }
        }
        },function (err,result) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({"success": '0', "message": "Error adding data"});
            }
            else {
                res.json({"success": '1', "message": "Data added"});
            }
        });
});
```

But the data is not inserted into table and no error is shown, I don't know what is the problem.

My user table is shown below:

[image: TABLE]

Comment: You don't specify which feed to push to. Try { $push : { feed.0.feedImages : { imageUrl : imageUrl } } }

Comment: tried that.. not working.........

Comment: But your method is working in mongo shell

Comment: Try this `{ $push : { feed.$.feedImages : { imageUrl : imageUrl } } } `.

Comment: if i use feed.0._id and feed.0.feedImages ,it is working.. but for the "$" its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$` to push in the matched element of the array. i.e. for which `feed._id` matches

Try this:

```
db.user.update(
        {"feed._id":_id },
        {$push : {
            "feed.$.feedImages":{
                imageUrl:imageUrl
            }
        }
        },function (err,result) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({"success": '0', "message": "Error adding data"});
            }
            else {
                res.json({"success": '1', "message": "Data added"});
            }
        });
```

**Edit**

`$` is `update positional operator`, which helps update only the element which matches the update criteria. For more info see [MongoDB $ operator Documentation.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#_S_)

Comment: if i use feed.0._id and feed.0.feedImages ,it is working.. but for the "$" its not working

Comment: It should be `feed._id` with `feed.$.feedImages` to get what you want. `feed._id` will search for the element of the array having that particular `id`, and `feed.$` will make sure that `update` happens to that matched element only. See the link i provided in the edit, to learn ,more about $(update positional operator)

Comment: when i use db.user.find({"_id":_id}), no results where returned.What will be the reason for that?? I think that will be the problem..

Comment: Are you using same `_id` for both `feed._id` and `_id`??

Comment: No they are different.In my question i had added the image of table. There you can see the two different  id's

Comment: what does it show you when you do `console.log(_id)`(do this before the find query)? Are you sure you are getting the correct _id from `req.body._id`.

Comment: yeah. its getting undefined value.why it is like that?